# EF4.1 Code First Mocking With Moq

Tags: unit-testing, moq, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I am trying my hand on EF with EF4.1 Code Frist. I have developed my models, like:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id{get;set;}
    [Column("first_name")]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string FristName{get;set;}
    //............
    //..............
}
```

I have written an interface also:

```
public interface IUser
{
    IDbSet<User> Users{get;}
}
```

My context class looks like this:

```
public class UserContext : DbContext, IUser
{
    public DbSet<User> Users{get;set;}

    IDbSet<User> IUser.Users{get return{Users;}}
}
```

Now I am at loss how to use Moq to mock this repository and do unit testing. Maybe I am new to unit testing with mocking.

Kindly advise me or point me to some resources where I can learn how to use Moq with EF4.1.

Answer (score 2):

A great pattern to use when mocking data access is the [Repository pattern and Unit of work](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).  When you have abstracted data access to a Repository interface you can use a mocking framework like [moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/). To provide you with a testable repository.

```
var mockUnitOfWork = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
mockUnitOfWork.SetupGet(p => p.UserRepository.GetSomeUsers)
.Returns(new List<User> { "Username", "email","etc"}));
```

You can then use the mockUnitOfWork and repository to test data access without having to hit the database as its only accessing an in memory list of users.